# Regular Expression re.sub not detecting all matches

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I've been trying to retrieve percentages from text using regular expressions. Sadly, using .sub does not retrieve all matches.

```
data = "Tho grades of the two students improved by 5.2% and 6.2%."
re_1 = re.compile(r"\b(\d+\.)?\d+(%|(\spercent))")
data = re.sub(re_1, "__PERCENTAGE__", data, re.I)
```

I'm trying to retrieve things such as: "5%","20.2%","5 percent","5.2 percent".
The word percent and percentage symbol being part of the match is fine but I suspect the trouble comes from overlap. When inputting the above data the current output is:

```
"The grades of the two students improved by __PERCENTAGE__ and 6.2%."
```

Any tips on how I could make sure both percentages turn up as matches? 
Thanks a lot.

PS: Might be relevant, I'm using Python 3

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the `g` flag to make it substitute all matches in a string.

Comment: As an aside, it is better to write `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` instead of `(?:\d+\.)?\d+` because all digits on the left side are matched once and for all even if there is no decimal point. When there is no decimal point the group fails immediatly.

Comment: It looks like this works. http://regexr.com/3atik

Answer (score 0):

The problem you might be having is related to the way `u` is handled in different Python 3 versions. Also, you are passing the compiled regex object to the `re.sub`, while only the string pattern should be passed as the first parameter.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\spercent|\%))')
test_str = "The grades of the two students improved by 5.2% and 5.4% it was 5 percent or 1.2%."
result = re.sub(p, "__PERCENTAGE__", test_str)
print (result)
```

In [IDEONE Demo](https://ideone.com/Vyj2G9) (uses Python 3.4), the code compiles well and outputs

```
The grades of the two students improved by __PERCENTAGE__ and __PERCENTAGE__ it was __PERCENTAGE__ or __PERCENTAGE__.
```

Comment: Ah, yes that might be the case. Thanks for the heads up on the compiled regex. I've noticed that only the first two matches are matched. 

[Ideone Code](https://ideone.com/zubn5v)

When I remove one of the first two percentages in the data it will match the next one but only the first two if I don't.

Comment: Please see an update. I mainly escape the `%` that has specific meaning in Python 3 strings.